# Full width Megamenu using only css

Tags: html, css

I want to develop a full width Mega menu
May kindly see this
http://codepen.io/tanmoy911/pen/KzjVdq

My CSS code is 12 column grid system

```
.fui-navbar{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden}
.fui-navbar li{float:left}.fui-navbar li a{display:block;padding:.5em 1em}.fui-navbar li a:hover{color:#000;background-color:#ccc}
.fui-navbar .fui-dropdown-hover,.fui-navbar .fui-dropdown-click{position:static}
.fui-navbar .fui-dropdown-hover:hover,.fui-navbar .fui-dropdown-hover:first-child,.fui-navbar .fui-dropdown-click:hover{background-color:#ccc;color:#000}
.fui-navbar a{text-decoration:none!important}
.fui-navbar .fui-right{float:right!important}
.fui-navbar a,fui-dropdown-content a
{-webkit-transition:background-color .3s,color .15s,box-shadow .3s,opacity 0.3s;transition:background-color .3s,color .15s,box-shadow .3s,opacity 0.3s}
.fui-dropdown-click,.fui-dropdown-hover{position:relative;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer}
.fui-dropdown-hover:hover .fui-dropdown-content{display:block;z-index:1}
.fui-dropdown-content{cursor:auto;color:#000;background-color:#fff;display:none;position:absolute;min-width:160px;margin:0;padding:0}
.fui-dropdown-content a{padding:6px 16px;display:block}
.fui-dropdown-content a:hover{background-color:#ccc}
.fui-container:after,.fui-row:after,.fui-row-padding:after,.fui-topnav:after,.fui-clear:after,.fui-btn-group:before,.fui-btn-group:after
{content:"";display:table;clear:both}

/*Grid System*/
.fui-col,.fui-half,.fui-third,.fui-twothird,.fui-threequarter,.fui-quarter{float:left;width:100%; padding: 0.375em;}
.fui-col,.fui-half,.fui-third,.fui-twothird,.fui-threequarter,.fui-quarter{float:left;width:100%}
.fui-col.l1{width:8.33333%}
.fui-col.l2{width:16.66666%}
.fui-col.l3,.fui-quarter{width:24.99999%}
.fui-col.l4,.fui-third{width:33.33333%}
.fui-col.l5{width:41.66666%}
.fui-col.l6,.fui-half{width:49.99999%}
.fui-col.l7{width:58.33333%}
.fui-col.l8,.fui-twothird{width:66.66666%}
.fui-col.l9,.fui-threequarter{width:74.99999%}
.fui-col.l10{width:83.33333%}
.fui-col.l11{width:91.66666%}
.fui-col.l12{width:99.99999%}
```

**HTML is**

```css
.fui-navbar{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden}
    .fui-navbar li{float:left}.fui-navbar li a{display:block;padding:.5em 1em}.fui-navbar li a:hover{color:#000;background-color:#ccc}
    .fui-navbar .fui-dropdown-hover,.fui-navbar .fui-dropdown-click{position:static}
    .fui-navbar .fui-dropdown-hover:hover,.fui-navbar .fui-dropdown-hover:first-child,.fui-navbar .fui-dropdown-click:hover{background-color:#ccc;color:#000}
    .fui-navbar a{text-decoration:none!important}
    .fui-navbar .fui-right{float:right!important}
    .fui-navbar a,fui-dropdown-content a
    {-webkit-transition:background-color .3s,color .15s,box-shadow .3s,opacity 0.3s;transition:background-color .3s,color .15s,box-shadow .3s,opacity 0.3s}
    .fui-dropdown-click,.fui-dropdown-hover{position:relative;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer}
    .fui-dropdown-hover:hover .fui-dropdown-content{display:block;z-index:1}
    .fui-dropdown-content{cursor:auto;color:#000;background-color:#fff;display:none;position:absolute;min-width:160px;margin:0;padding:0}
    .fui-dropdown-content a{padding:6px 16px;display:block}
    .fui-dropdown-content a:hover{background-color:#ccc}
    .fui-container:after,.fui-row:after,.fui-row-padding:after,.fui-topnav:after,.fui-clear:after,.fui-btn-group:before,.fui-btn-group:after
    {content:"";display:table;clear:both}
    
    /*Grid System*/
    .fui-col,.fui-half,.fui-third,.fui-twothird,.fui-threequarter,.fui-quarter{float:left;width:100%; padding: 0.375em;}
    .fui-col,.fui-half,.fui-third,.fui-twothird,.fui-threequarter,.fui-quarter{float:left;width:100%}
    .fui-col.l1{width:8.33333%}
    .fui-col.l2{width:16.66666%}
    .fui-col.l3,.fui-quarter{width:24.99999%}
    .fui-col.l4,.fui-third{width:33.33333%}
    .fui-col.l5{width:41.66666%}
    .fui-col.l6,.fui-half{width:49.99999%}
    .fui-col.l7{width:58.33333%}
    .fui-col.l8,.fui-twothird{width:66.66666%}
    .fui-col.l9,.fui-threequarter{width:74.99999%}
    .fui-col.l10{width:83.33333%}
    .fui-col.l11{width:91.66666%}
    .fui-col.l12{width:99.99999%}
```

```html
<ul class="fui-navbar fui-card-2 fui-light-grey">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li class="fui-dropdown-hover">
        <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="fui-dropdown-content fui-white fui-card-4">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="fui-navbar fui-large fui-left-align">
       <header class="fui-container fui-white fui-large">
          <ul class="fui-navbar">
            <li><a class="fui-padding-24 fui-text-brown fui-hover-blue fui-serif" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="fui-padding-24 fui-text-brown fui-hover-blue fui-serif" href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li class="fui-dropdown-hover"> <a class="fui-padding-24 fui-text-brown fui-hover-blue fui-serif" href="#">Menu &#9662;</a>
              <div class="fui-dropdown-content" style="background-color:#F5EEAF">
                <ul class="fui-navbar fui-Black fui-left-align">
                  <div class="fui-col fui-container m3 l3">
                    <li><a href="index.html" >Homepage</a></li>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <li><a href="portfolio1.html">Our Work (Portfolio)</a></li>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <li><a  href="portfolio1.html">Portfolio of Recon Industries</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="portfolioitem.html">Portfolio Item Description</a></li>
                    <br/>
                    <li><a>Services and Features</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="services.html">Services/Features</a></li>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fui-col fui-container m3 l3">
                    <li><a class="fui-text-brown fui-serif fui-tag">Product Details</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="products.html">Products listing </a></li>
                    <li><a  href="productdetails.html">Product Details</a></li>
                    <li><a class="fui-text-brown fui-serif fui-tag" href="productdetails.html">Recon Industries Blog </a></li>
                    <li><a href="blogposts.html">Blog Posts</a></li>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fui-col fui-container m3 l3">
                    <li><a>General Pages</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="faq.html">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="testimonialsclients.html">Testimonials & Clients</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="404.html">404 Page (Page Not Found )</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="termsprivacy.html">Terms & Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="comingsoon.html">Coming Soon</a></li>
                  </div>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li> <a class="fui-padding-24 fui-text-brown fui-hover-blue fui-serif" href="credits.html">Credits</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </header>
    </ul>
```

Now I want the menu should be full width or 100% width. That can be achieved separately. I know but I am stuck with my existing code.

How I can change my code so that It shows the menu in full width. Like http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page193/mpurpose

Pls help.

Comment: Can you put this in jsfiddle? It will help a lot to figure out what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Pls see this https://jsfiddle.net/tanmoy911/1ynmqwou/.

Comment: So you want  your second menu tab should  be in full width means no left blank space, right?

Comment: Yes sir like this http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page193/mpurpose. Without affecting my dropdown

Comment: Like this http://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/bpPEmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are just missing `left:0` so

Create a new class(.ff-left) and add with fui-dropdown-content class so it won't affect the top menu.

```
.ff-left{left:0;}
```

See [here](http://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/WwqrYd)